porque no puedo migrar mis tablas de laravel a mysql me da este error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Querida comunidad si alguien ya pudo solucionar este tipo de error me podria ayudar, ya llevo como casi dos semanas buscando el error incluso cree un nuevo proyecto, mi MySQL de workbench esta bien configurado porque puedo ingresar hasta de la consola, puedo conectarme usando php sin framework, ahora cuando lo uso con laravel para migrar, me sale este error. Se los agradezco mucho.
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 
(Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as name, (data_length + index_length) as size, 
table_comment as comment, engine as engine, table_collation as collation from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'devstagram' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)



El usuario root en host localhost con uso de contraseña, tiene el acceso denegado. Muestra el archivo de configuración de la conexión de laravel.

este es mi configuracion: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_prueba
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=tengo pass

Prueba a poner localhost en vez de la IP, y para añadir datos, edita la publicacion, no lo añadas como comentario (agrega el archivo entero, no solo el pedazo de conexión)

Métete en el cliente MySQL de terminal y escribe esto a ver si así lo permite: ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'tengopass'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;  y sustituye el "tengopass" por tu pass correcta para el usuario root, y dale al enter

Estás haciendo una consulta a la BBDD information_schema, revisa los permisos de root sobre esa BBDD.

cómo puede ser que en tun .env tengas DB_HOST=127.0.0.1  y en el error esté diciendo que intentas conectarte a localhost ?
